# Negative curl timeout

Tags: curl, connection-timeout

What happens when you use a negative curl timeout?

$curlOptions[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = -2;

Does it get transformed into positive 2, or remains -2?

Because, sometimes curl works, sometimes doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how curl works:

First it connects to the url that you provide.

Then it perform the overall curl operation for the amount of seconds you have specified through the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` option.

So if you set the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` as -2 it will never execute after connecting to the host. To verify this, run the script by enabling the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option. And you'll get the following msg always.

```
* Operation timed out after -2000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Comment: The who case scenario was: CURLOPT_TIMEOUT = -2, CONNECT TIMEOUT = 1;

How this sometimes worked, sometimes didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a negative timeout ? it doesn't make any sense. Either curl gets the page and quits or wait until the it's completes loading, for that you use a POSITIVE value, bellow it's an example on how to use curl with timeout:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://site/test/test_timeout.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //timeout in seconds - You can use 0 for infinite timeout
/* You can also use
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000); //timeout in miliseconds (5 seconds)
*/
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Curl Timeout Options:**

`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`
 The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`
 The number of milliseconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely. If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the connect will still use full-second resolution for timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second.  Added in cURL 7.16.2. Available since PHP 5.2.3.